# Flutter- run a method everyday at specific time

Tags: flutter

i want to know if there is a way to make the app itself to run a method every 24h. or run it at 12 AM everyday (even if the app is closed all the day). the idea about that is lets say for example that i have to implement a method that delete documents in firebase. so i need these documents to be deleted everyday at 12 AM

is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Yes.  If you can't guarantee that your app is running either foreground or background at the appointed time, you'll need to use FCM, particularly if you're on ios.  On android, you can schedule tasks in a cron-like manner.